# Will Shaivism and Vaishnavism merge, if some one proves Vishnu and Siva to be the same?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, vaishnavism, shaivism

I do not know much about whether there are any other fundamental differences between these two sects. The only difference I know is that the Vaishnavites believe Vishnu alone as their primary deity (Brahman) and Shaivites believe that Siva slone as primary deity.

Will they cease to exist independently and merge as one if proof exists that Siva and Vishnu are one and the same or **any other issues are also needed to be sorted out apart from that**?

Comment: Please mention reason also after or before down-voting so that i will adjust myself accordingly

Comment: Do you know Hari hara?

Comment: @hanugm: There are some members, who simply downvote, without mentioning the reasons thereof.  Even many of my questions and answers were downvoted.  The moderators are simply watching, even though the same was flagged off once.  May be due to sectarian attitude.

Comment: If they merge, they would loose themselves. I hope they remail independant. If you try to merge Vishnu and Shiva worship, that would be like creating a new Hinduism - one place for Shiva and VIshnu worship.

Comment: @hanugm: what is there to be proven again?  Rig Veda already stated that Vishnu and Indra and Rudra are one and the same

Comment: No they would never converge for a multitude of reasons. The pujas are different, the mantra which they hold dearly, the books they elevate are different.

Answer (score -4):

There are many confirmed proves

**1.**In MahaNarayana Upanishad, 
Confirmed that Ganesh, Shakti, Brahma, Narayana, Rudra are one. Everything is done him or her. {Sorry Everyone those who related upper God related community please read them.} Statement is 
**Lord Ganesh gives movement to our brain, Goddess Shakti gives Energy to do work,
Lord Brahma gives ability to create or Start,
Lord Narayana gives ability to hold or preserve, Lord Rudra gives ability to destroy or end it.**

2. Lord Vishnu Sahasranamam of Garuda Purana
3. Purusha Suktam, Rig Veda
4. Yajur Veda Sandhyavandanam

**Shivaaya Vishnu Roopaya Shiva Roopaya Vishnave**

So, don't leave your abode those chanted you.

1. Those Vaishnavs who that his abode is superior other are nothing. So stop receiving any Subject of it because Every abode is situated everywhere.Because they are in one form that is Brahm